# Error de sintaxis al ejecutar rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby, migration

Estoy siguiendo un curso en línea de desarrollo web para generar una aplicación, he estado utilizando ubuntu para la instalación de ruby on rails, y he corrido los siguientes comandos:

```
rails new hello_WWW
cd hello_www
rails generate scaffold pioneer first_name:string last_name:string
```

pero al correr `rake db:migrate` recibo esto:

```
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:110: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /root/hello_WWW/db/migrate/20200413005922_create_pioneers.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':'
      t.string : first_name
               ^

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución está en el error. Te da toda la información que necesitas:

```
SyntaxError: /root/hello_WWW/db/migrate/20200413005922_create_pioneers.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':'
      t.string : first_name
```

`SyntaxError` dice que es un error de sintaxis, o en otras palabras, escribiste algo mal que no puede ser interpretado por ruby.
`/root/hello_WWW/db/migrate/20200413005922_create_pioneers.rb:4` te dice el archivo y la línea (4) donde se originó el error.
Finalmente en:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':'
      t.string : first_name
```

te explica que no esperaba encontrar un `:` solo, que de hecho es algo que no se usa en ruby. Lo que espera un `t.string` es un [`symbol`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/02/ruby-symbols/) como parámetro. Para que funcione, debería ser como:

```
      t.string :first_name
```